# unexplained syntax error in for loop

Tags: python, syntax

I'm getting a syntax error on the 2nd to last line here, but don't know why. It seems identical to the line 2 lines before it, but for some reason I'm getting a syntax error. I've tried it both with and without a blank line between it and the line before it, with the same results.

```
## numlist = some list
array_size = 20
for row in xrange(array_size):
    for col in xrange(array_size):
        if(col<=(array_size-4)):
            check(sum(numlist[row][col:col+4])
        if(row<=(array_size-4)):
            check(sum([numlist[row+i][col] for i in range(4)]))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing a closing `')'` for the statement below the first `if`-statement.

```
check(sum(numlist[row][col:col+4])
                                  ^
```

should be

```
check(sum(numlist[row][col:col+4]))
                                  ^
```

*Note*: Using an editor with the feature that [matches/highlights parens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brace_matching) is a very useful tool to have and will save you from spending time finding these sort of errors.

Answer (score 5):

```
check(sum(numlist[row][col:col+4])
```

Should be:

```
check(sum(numlist[row][col:col+4]))
```

note the extra parenthesis at the end

Comment: whoever just opvoted: NOOOOOO I WAS AT 1337 REPUTATION AND YOU KILLED IT :(